# Check if a shader storage block is read-only

Tags: opengl, opengl-es

In my OpenGL program I need to find a way to differentiate writable shader storage blocks from read-only shader storage blocks. In other words I need to be able to detect glsl code like this:

```
layout(std140) readonly buffer StorageBuffer
{
    vec4 data;
}g_Buffer;
```

[glGetProgramResourceiv](https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenGL-Refpages/gl4/html/glGetProgramResource.xhtml) does not seem to provide this information. Is there another way to check this?

Comment: But... it's *your shader*. If you don't know something like whether a block is a read-only block, how would you be expected to be able to use it? I mean, presumably that block has some semantic meaning to your program, right? Shouldn't that semantic meaning include whether the shader is going to write to it? The only way I can see where this would be useful is if you're writing OpenGL code that needs to shape itself to any arbitrary shader it is given. But even then, how exactly would knowing whether an SSBO is written to by the shader change things?

Comment: My system uses elaborate shader resource reflection system. Based on the type of GLSL shader storage block, there are different options for which resource it is legal to bind to that shader variable. I have this information in D3D11, D3D12 and Vulkan, but as usual, things become very fuzzy when it comes to OpenGL

Comment: The only way you would have this information in Vulkan is if you were using some kind of SPIR-V parser to deduce it, since Vulkan has absolutely no reflection API whatsoever. In which case, you could just compile your GLSL to OpenGL-flavored SPIR-V and use your existing tools on it.

Comment: @NicolBolas So I guess you suggestion means that the answer to my original question is "No" because on platforms that don't support Vulkan I don't want to use SPIRV toolchain to get this information.

Comment: ... what? Vulkan has no reflection API. As such, the presence or absence of Vulkan support is utterly irrelevant. You could just build a secondary file to be loaded with the shader that provides supplementary information if you don't want to incorporate glslang into your application.

Comment: @NicolBolas, yes, this is what I meant. I don't want to have dependency on glslang and SPIRV-Cross just to check if a storage buffer is read-only.

Comment: @NicolBolas I appreciate your suggestions, but I am 100% confident in what I am doing, so I'd really like to know the answer to my original question which refers to OpenGL. I already suspect that there is no way to do this, but I wanted to double check.